# Create Entity with a list of objects as atribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, entity

right now i am developing a simple web app, with .NET CORE MVC, and i structured my project like this:
[image]

And now i have a problem, I have 2 entities, on which, one is Product and the other one is Order
And the Order entity.
On the frontend i have a list of products, that are sent, when you buy, to the back-end
And after that, a new Order with that list of Products is created, the problem is, when i "Buy" the products i always Get an null Exception

My Product Entity:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Domain.Entities
{
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int ProductPrice { get; set; }


        public Product(string productName, int productPrice)
        {
            this.ProductName = productName;
            this.ProductPrice = productPrice;
        }

        public void ApplyDiscounts(int discountValue) 
        {
            if (discountValue >= this.ProductPrice) 
            {
                this.ProductPrice -= discountValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Order entity:

```
using Domain.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Product> ProductList { get; private set; }
        public Order()
        {

        }

        public Order AddProducts(IEnumerable<Product> productListToAdd) 
        {

            foreach (var product in productListToAdd) 
            {
                ProductList.ToList().Add(product);
            }

            return this;
        }

    }
}
```

Is this the right way?
Appreciate in advance

Comment: Unless you've shared the code for where the null pointer exception happens, you should probably consider sharing it, if you want some help.

Anyway, if you did share it, is ProductList in AddProducts() null?

Comment: yes i shared where the NullPointerException happens, my bad, its in AddProducts(), like you said, and i fixed it by instantianting the IEnumerable<Product> in the constructor, but now i get `UNIQUE constraint failed: Products.ProductID` when i try to save to the DB, after adding the values to the collection

Comment: Hello was the problem resolved?

Comment: i dont get the same error, but still cant retrieve the list

Comment: Share your controller and read-write operational code on database so that we can easily get into that.